# How do I recover from internal bleeding?

Tags: neo-scavenger

Apparently, during an epic battle with a barefoot looter in *NEO Scavenger*, I ended up with a broken rib and some internal bleeding.

Fortunately for me, I took the **Medical** perk at the start of the game! There's just one small problem, I have no idea how that perk will help me with fractured bones and internal bleeding.

**How can I make sure I don't die from this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way (yet) to treat that specific condition. One simply has to give it time to heal, and stay hydrated/warm/etc in the meantime. It goes away when the injury that caused it heals (e.g. a severe torso wound).

The good news is that it won't escalate if left unattended. As long as you can cope with the loss of water, it'll leave you otherwise unharmed. (The only other side effect is that it slightly reduces the rate that your blood supply restores.)

Two things to note:

1 - Things that increase healing rates, like resting/sleeping, hanging out in campsites, and the nanorobotic medkit, also increase the rate at which this condition goes away.

2 - This condition stacks, meaning multiple wounds that cause internal bleeding will multiply the effects.

Hopefully, some day I can add more cool stuff for medics to do with wounds. For now, they simply have a slightly higher healing rate, which is meant to simulate their knowledge of caring for wounds, avoiding infection, and protecting the wounds from re-injury.

Comment: Awesome. I figure now is as good a time as any to thank you for the effort you've put into answering questions here. It's fairly uncommon for a game's dev to participate as actively as you have! So, thank you, and nice job on the game!

Comment: No problem! I like to bang around the net and help folks out with the game where I can. I can't be everywhere at once, but it's hard for me to resist replying if I stumble across something :) And thanks for the encouragement! Glad to hear your enjoying it so far!

Comment: i think it changed in the meanwhile, there are nanorobot medical kits, these might work